# Sorting a list but the sort order isn't known until runtime

Tags: java, sorting

I need to sort a list of strings that I'm reading in but the sorted order of that list is not predetermined (I can't hard code it); I read in the sort order from a source and build a comparator by assigning a numerical value to each entry in a map and then use that to determine the order.

My implementation is pretty simple and straightforward. I don't know if there is any room to optimize this but given that sorting is generally a slow process in itself, I wanted to submit this for code review in case there are in fact any improvements to be made.

The custom comparator will be cached after creation so I won't be building a new one unless required to do so.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class RunTest {
   // Runnable test
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      CustomComparator comparator = CustomComparator.fromList(getSortOrder());
      
      List<String> list1 = getTestList();
      
      System.out.println("Test list: \n  " + list1);
      
      Collections.sort(list1, comparator);
      
      System.out.println("Test list (sorted): \n  " + list1);
   }
   
   // Comparator
   public static class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {
      private Map<String, Integer> _sortOrder;
      
      public CustomComparator(Map<String, Integer> sortOrder) {
         _sortOrder = sortOrder;
      }
      
      @Override
      public int compare(String l, String r) {
         Integer lvalue = _sortOrder.get(l);
         Integer rvalue = _sortOrder.get(r);
         
         if (lvalue == null || rvalue == null)
            return 0;
         
         if (lvalue < rvalue)
            return -1;
         
         return 1;
      }
      
      public static CustomComparator fromList(List<String> sortOrder) {
         // Map each list item to a comparable integer
         Map<String, Integer> customSortOrder = new HashMap<>();
         
         int i = 0;
         
         for (String s : sortOrder)
            customSortOrder.put(s, i++);
         
         return new CustomComparator(customSortOrder);
      }
   }
   
   // Custom sort order
   public static List<String> getSortOrder() {
      List<String> customSortOrder = new LinkedList<>();
      
      customSortOrder.add("c");
      customSortOrder.add("b");
      customSortOrder.add("a");
      
      return customSortOrder;
   }
   
   // Test list
   public static List<String> getTestList() {
      List<String> randomList = new LinkedList<>();
      
      randomList.add("b");
      randomList.add("a");
      randomList.add("c");
      
      return randomList;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Test list:
  [b, a, c]
Test list (sorted):
  [c, b, a]
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
     if (lvalue == null || rvalue == null)
        return 0;
```

doesn't seem very safe. It says that if *either* of the values does not have a defined order, then don't care about the order, consider them equivalent. This will have the effect of interleaving such items throughout your sorted list.

Technically this fails the requirement of [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive

In other words, given some strings `a`, `b` and `c` with ordering indices 1, `null` and 2, your existing implementation will say that `a` == `b`, `b` == `c` but `a` != `c` - this is non-transitive.

Instead: either throw an exception if there is a value with an undefined order; or choose to default undefined-order values at the beginning or end of the list.

Answer (score 3):

```java
// Runnable test
```

[Javadoc](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html)

---

```java
private Map<String, Integer> _sortOrder;
```

The Java convention does not use underscores to mark fields or members. You'd use the name and then prefix it with `this.` as needed. Obviously, that's still up to you what you use.

---

```java
      private Map<String, Integer> _sortOrder;
      
      public CustomComparator(Map<String, Integer> sortOrder) {
         _sortOrder = sortOrder;
      }
```

That allows `_sortOrder` to be changed from outside the class during runtime, mind you.

---

```java
      public int compare(String l, String r) {
         Integer lvalue = _sortOrder.get(l);
         Integer rvalue = _sortOrder.get(r);
```

Don't shorten names just because you can! Shortened names only lead to less readable and less maintainable code.

---

```java
         if (lvalue < rvalue)
            return -1;
         
         return 1;
```

That's incorrect, as far as I can see. If both values match you're returning `1`, which is not correct and might lead to an endless loop depending on how the sorting algorithm works. `Comparator`s are supposed to return `-1/0/1`, but all implementations are compelled/supposed to also accept `-n/0/n`. SO you can simply subtract both values and return the result:

```java
return lvalue.intValue() - rvalue.intValue();
```

---

```java
         int i = 0;
         
         for (String s : sortOrder)
            customSortOrder.put(s, i++);
```

Be aware of [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

And again, don't shorten names.

```java
         int value = 0;
         
         for (String item : sortOrder) {
            customSortOrderMap.put(item, Integer.valueOf(value++));
         }
```

Whether or not you use braces for single lines, is again up to you, it's advised against, though.

---

```java
List<String> customSortOrder = new LinkedList<>();
```

By default you'd be using an `ArrayList`, as it is the cheapest implementation when it comes to various operations, that include adding and removing.

---

There's not much else to say about the actual logic, as far as I can see it should work.

Using a `Map` as intermediate object might not be the nicest choice. Instead, you could allow to modify the `Comparator`.

```java
public class ValueBasedComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();
    
    public ValueBasedComparator addValue(String item, int value) {
        values.put(item, Integer.valueOf(value));
    }
}
```

Also, I believe you could use generics to make the class generic:

```java
   public static class CustomComparator<ITEM_TYPE> implements Comparator<ITEM_TYPE> {
      private Map<ITEM_TYPE, Integer> _sortOrder;

      @Override
      public int compare(ITEM_TYPE first, ITEM_TYPE second) {
```

But there might be an edge-case not allowing that, have not tested it.